# Why are my UITableDelegate methods not being called?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a very simple iOS app in Swift, barely more than a **Hello, world**, and I cannot get anything to appear on the screen. It builds and runs without error, but when I run it on either a simulated evice or a physical device all that is shown is a solid black screen.

This is the main class, **AppDelegate**:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var flowController: AppFlowController? // see below
    
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication
        ,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        flowController = AppFlowController(window: window!)
        flowController!.start()
        
        return true
    }
}
```

This is a class that I hope to use eventually for isolating flow logic:

```
class AppFlowController {
    let window: UIWindow
    
    init(window: UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
        print("flow controller constructed")
    }
    
    func start() {
        let viewController = DerivedViewController() // see below
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        print("window brought to top")
    }
}
```

This is the **UITableViewController**-derived class I'm trying and failing to use to manage a **UITableView**:

```
class DerivedViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        print("viewDidLoad")
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("number of sections")
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("number of rows")
        return 4
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Text"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Subtext"
        print("cell for row \(indexPath.row) created")
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's the console output:

```
flow controller constructed
viewDidLoad
number of sections
window brought to top
```

Clearly the **tableView()** delegate methods are never being called, but I'm darned if I understand why not. I've been through the Apple developer doc and multiple tutorials on **UITableViewController**, and don't yet see what I'm missing. **UITableViewController** makes itself the delegate for its **UITableView**, do I understand that right?.

Comment: I tried your code in a project and it renders the rows for me. Do you have a scene delegate? As you are loading programatically have you removed the references to the `Main.storyboard` from the `Info.plist`?

Comment: Xcode 12 doesn't seem to have storyboards. But I tried running grep -ir 'board' ./* in the top directory of the project, and it turned up no results. I don't see any scene delegate; certainly the template didn't create one, and neither did I.

Comment: They do if you set you project up with an AppDelegate and an interface of Storyboard. If you have setup your app with a SwiftUI as a base then it won't have one. If you have chosen a SwiftUI project it will be more complex to build your code with UIKit programatically but it isn't impossible. Without knowing how you have set your project up it makes it difficult to debug. You should take a look at [this](https://learnappmaking.com/scene-delegate-app-delegate-xcode-11-ios-13/), as it might shed some light on your problem.

Comment: I added your code to a SceneDelegate project, and it worked fine once I deleted the storyboard, the scene delegate and all the associated entries in the Info.plist. If you have them they will be visible in Xcode - the Info plist entry is called `Application Scene Manifest`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this worked, since I'm quite new to Xcode, but I noticed a difference in my app and a working example I studying, which was that on mine the value in **info.plist** of **Bundle OS Type code** was `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)` and on the one that worked it was `APPL`. When I changed mine to `APPL`, it displayed as expected.

I guess that variable wasn't being resolved correctly, or was being set incorrectly in some way; I certainly didn't change it on purpose, being unaware of its existence.